# Calculating a share value group by in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I want to calculate percentage of value in Group by. My table data:

| id | date | artist | track | listenings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | C | track_1 | 2016 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | C | track_2 | 3800 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | B | track_3 | 2311 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | A | track_4 | 4180 |
| 5 | 2023-01-01 | C | track_5 | 2013 |
| 6 | 2023-01-01 | A | track_6 | 2227 |
| 7 | 2023-01-01 | B | track_7 | 1006 |
| 8 | 2023-01-01 | B | track_8 | 720 |
| 9 | 2023-01-01 | A | track_9 | 2438 |
| 10 | 2023-01-01 | A | track_10 | 2654 |
| 11 | 2023-01-02 | C | track_1 | 3347 |
| 12 | 2023-01-02 | C | track_2 | 3100 |
| 13 | 2023-01-02 | B | track_3 | 2436 |
| 14 | 2023-01-02 | A | track_4 | 4821 |
| 15 | 2023-01-02 | C | track_5 | 1485 |
| 16 | 2023-01-02 | A | track_6 | 3157 |
| 17 | 2023-01-02 | B | track_7 | 1993 |
| 18 | 2023-01-02 | B | track_8 | 2953 |
| 19 | 2023-01-02 | A | track_9 | 1651 |
| 20 | 2023-01-02 | A | track_10 | 1260 |

I need to calculate the share of listens to the track from listenings to all tracks of one artist for each date for each of the artists. The output table must be like

| id | date | artist | track | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | C | track_1 | 0.257 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | C | track_2 | 0.486 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | B | track_3 | 0.572 |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 | A | track_4 | 0.364 |
| 5 | 2023-01-01 | C | track_5 | 0.257 |
| 11 | 2023-01-02 | C | track_1 | 0.422 |

and so on. Please help me to write this script.

Answer (score 1):

Using a subquery to find the total number of listens per artist, per date:

```
select t.*, round(cast(t.listenings as numeric)/cast((select sum(t1.listenings) 
    from tracks t1 
    where t1.artist = t.artist and t.date = t1.date) as numeric), 3) 
from tracks t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rxAsE8h2)

Answer (score 1):

Just use window functions!

```
select t.*,
    listenings::numeric 
    / sum(listenings) over(partition by artist, date) pct
from tracks
```